# Weblogic takes time to startup

Tags: redhat, weblogic

I installed weblogic 9.2.3 on Linux redhat 5.5 but I have weird error which is that it takes a long time to startup.

So when I have to restart weblogic first I have to reboot Linux server then startup again weblogic here you can see the logs

```
<Mar 31, 2011 11:53:05 AM CEST> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with BEA JRockit(R) Version R27.4.0-90_CR358515-94243-1.5.0_12-20080118-1154-linux-ia32 from BEA Systems, Inc.>
<Mar 31, 2011 11:53:06 AM CEST> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 9.2 MP3  Mon Mar 10 08:28:41 EDT 2008 1096261 >
```

Hope I explained well!

What kind of error is this one?

Comment: Logs:<Mar 31, 2011 12:01:22 PM CEST> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with BEA JRockit(R) Version R27.4.0-90_CR358515-94243-1.5.0_12-20080118-1154-linux-ia32 from BEA Systems, Inc.>
<Mar 31, 2011 12:01:23 PM CEST> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 9.2 MP3  Mon Mar 10 08:28:41 EDT 2008 1096261 >

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have stuck at similar inadequate weblogic behavior: http://serverfault.com/questions/260395/weblogic-administration-console-way-too-slow

Answer (score 1):

First check how many JDBC connection pools do you have.

If there are many which you are not using try to remove them

If you want to use them change the initial pool size and make it zero.

Answer (score 0):

check your DNS configuration it may help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I already did it, another idea?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a variety of things, are you deploying many apps on startup or starting a vanilla weblogic server.

Is there DB connectivity established, or is it taking time to do that?

I assume you have a single server, and not any cluster related issue. Can you post more detailed logs ? The current one just shows 2 lines with a 1 second gap.